# I am trying to get active carousel id when click to button using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to get active carousel id when i click to button for next carousel please help me thanks.

**Note :-** I want to get the active carousel room id this should be 140 room id insteasd of 142 in console.

[image]

**Html view**

```
                             <div class="carousel-item {{$key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}  d-flex align- 
                                      items-center">
                                          <img src="{{ Config('wfh.file') . $roomImage}}" 
                                          height="113px" alt="First slide">
                                          <div class="ms-4">
                                              <h6 class="fw-bold">{{$value->name}}</h6>
                                              <input type="text" class="room_id"  name="room_id" value="{{$value->id}}" >
                                              <span class="badge bg-light-outline p-2 me-1"> <i class="bx bx-user"></i>{{$value->capacity ?? null }}</span>
                                              <span class="badge bg-primary p-2">Starts from PTS {{$value->points ?? null }}</span>
                                          </div>
                              </div>
```

**jquery**

```
  $(".butonSubmit").click(function(){

        // let crousalActive= $(".carousel-item").hasClass('active');

        if($(".carousel-item").hasClass('active') ){

            let room_id = $(".carousel-item.active .room_id").val();

            console.log(room_id);
        }

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many carousel-items do you have?
It probably takes the value of the first carousel-item.
Otherwise, try once without the default value.

Comment: I have 4 carousel-items

Comment: when i click to arraw for next carousel then i am getting 140 room id whereas i want to get active room id.

Comment: Does this mean that the room_id value can be read before moving the active class to the next item?
Probably, the problem can be solved by rewriting the event of the next and previous buttons.

Comment: Hi Samavi, your answer might have been better added as a comment under the question instead. It seems to be something to clarify the questions instead of providing a detailed solution.